display the files that i fetched from a github repositpory in my browser
i want to display the files i fetched from a github repository in my page and i think the code is good but i don't know why it doesn't display
this is the code of the react App:
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Lending from './pages/lending page/Lending';
import Scan from './pages/scan/Scan'
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Lending />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/scan">
        <Scan />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
};

export default App

and this is the code of Scan.jsx:
import React from 'react'
import {Chat, Code, Files, Navbar, Import} from '../../components';
import {ImportProvider} from '../../components/code/ImportContext';
import './scan.css';
const Scan = () => {
  return (
    <div className="vertical-layout">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <div className="left-section" >
          <ImportProvider>
            <Import />
            <Files />
          </ImportProvider>
        </div>
        <div className="code-section" >
          <ImportProvider>
            <Code />
          </ImportProvider>
        </div>
        <div className="right-section" >
          <Chat />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Scan

this is the code of Import.jsx:
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import Web3 from 'web3';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ImportContext} from '../code/ImportContext';
import './import.css'
const Import = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const { setCodeOrFiles } = useContext(ImportContext);
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };
  
  async function fetchFilesFromGitHub(repoUrl) {
    const url = new URL(repoUrl);
    const pathSegments = url.pathname.split('/'); // Split at first slash
    const owner = pathSegments[1];
    const repoName = pathSegments[2];
    const apiUrl =  `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repoName}/contents`;
    console.log("Constructed API URL:", apiUrl.replace(/\{owner\}/g, owner).replace(/\{repoName\}/g, repoName)); // Replace placeholders with actual values before logging
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
      console.log("API Response:", response); // Log the response object
      if (response.data) {
        const files = await Promise.all(response.data.map(async (file) => {
          // Fetch content for each file
          const contentResponse = await axios.get(file.download_url);
          return { ...file, content: contentResponse.data };
        }));
        return files;
      } else {
        throw new Error('No content found for the repository');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error fetching files from GitHub: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
  const handleImport = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setErrorMessage('');
    try {
      const files = await fetchFilesFromGitHub(inputValue);
      console.log('Fetched files:', files);
      setCodeOrFiles(files); // Pass the imported files to the context
      console.log('Code or contract imported successfully:', files);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage('Error importing:', error.message);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  {/*
  async function importSmartContract(contractAddress) {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum || 'wss://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_ID'); // Replace with your provider
    try {
      const code = await web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress);
      const abi = await web3.eth.abi.decodeContract(code); // Decode ABI (optional)
      return { code, abi }; // Return code and potentially ABI
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error importing smart contract: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
*/}
  return (
    <div className='import'>
      <input className='import_input' type="text" placeholder="Enter GitHub repository or smart contract address" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      <button className='import_button' onClick={handleImport} disabled={isLoading}>
        {isLoading ? '' : 'Import'} 
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Import

this is the code of Files.jsx:
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { ImportContext } from '../code/ImportContext';
import './files.css';
const File = ({ file }) => {
  const { importedFiles } = useContext(ImportContext);
  console.log('Consumed importedFiles:', importedFiles);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleOpen = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  if (file.type === 'dir') {
    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={toggleOpen}>Directory: {file.name} {isOpen ? '-' : '+'}</p>
        {isOpen && (
          <div style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}>
            {file.content.map((subFile) => (
              <File key={subFile.name} file={subFile} />
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>File: {file.name}</p>
        {file.content && <pre>{file.content}</pre>}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const Files = () => {
  const { importedFiles } = useContext(ImportContext);

  return (
    <div className='files'>
      {importedFiles.length > 0 ? (
        importedFiles.map((file) => <File key={file.name} file={file} />)
      ) : (
        <p>No files imported yet.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Files;

and this is the code of ImportContext.js:
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const ImportContext = createContext();

export const ImportProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [importedFiles, setImportedFiles] = useState([]);

  const setCodeOrFiles = (data) => {
    setImportedFiles(data);
    console.log('Updated importedFiles:', data);
  };

  const contextValue = { importedFiles, setCodeOrFiles };

  return (
    <ImportContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ImportContext.Provider>
  );
};


can you help me please ! to display them like in the picture(https://i.sstatic.net/eUAcJ2vI.png)
this is the github repository url that i'm making tests on it:
https://github.com/aya-kd/Constellation-Hackathon-23
i expect to display the files in the browser like in this website:
https://app.auditwizard.io/project/66100e73257ad87977adae25

what happens when you run the code? what debugging have you tried to far?

after running the code :
in the browser console returns an API response with the data fatched from the github but it doesn't displayed in the Files.jsx
